# Textbox in modal popup freezes up sometimes in FF

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, modal-dialog

I have a textbox in an `Ajax ModalPopUp`. Occasionally, whenever the modal is loaded, the textbox freezes in Firefox. It's not happening in Internet Explorer - **just Firefox**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please improve your question? What do you mean by freeze up? Can you not click to place focus into it? Can you tab into the input box? Does it freeze immediately, or only after you've typed for a while?

Comment: Yes I can't click in the textbox to write anything.Nope I can't put tab into textbox as well. It freezes intermittently.

Comment: Can you please post a stripped-down example, or a link to one?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, just maybe, it's because you have some code that clears the Textbox just before the dialog is shown? And maybe, just maybe, that code goes into a loop? I've seen many places where this happens - that a Textbox is both written-to and read-from. And when too many GUI updates are happening, Firefox can take much longer, and even peg the CPU at 100%, before resuming activity. MSIE doesn't do this as often - it either crashes or just delivers stale data from the Textbox.

Remove the code that clears the textbox and that should help. Good luck!